# SAP Hana Vora : Failed to fetch vora table from hadoop to Hana

Tags: vora

I have created a vora table using spark-vora and then create a virtual table in Hana Studio. when i am going to query that table in Hana studio it doesn't return anything to me. Even don't get error message too.

Could you please help me here to get data from virtual tables in Hana Studio.

Thanks,
Akash

Comment: Which version of Vora, Spark Controller and HANA are you using? Could you also add the content of the Spark Controller log /var/log/hanaes/hana_controller.log from the time the issue happens?

Comment: Frank, I am using Vora 1.2 and Spark Controller 1.5.8 and Hana SPS10. Please find below the content of hana_controller.log file

Comment: 16/05/06 14:14:25 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/06 14:14:25 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/06 14:14:25 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/06 14:14:25 WARN ParametersValidator: Parameter zkurls is deprecated and will be ignored.
16/05/06 14:14:25 WARN ParametersValidator: Parameter hosts is deprecated and will be ignored.

Comment: 16/05/06 14:14:25 INFO CatalogFactory: returning a Vora catalog client of this Vora catalog server: ip-172-30-1-173.ec2.internal:2204
16/05/06 14:14:25 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/06 14:14:25 INFO DefaultSource: Creating VoraRelation table001 using an existing catalog table
16/05/06 14:14:25 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/06 14:14:57 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer

Comment: HANA SPS10 is one problem. Vora 1.2 requires Spark Controller 1.5. Patch 5 (controller-1.5.8.jar) which in turn requires HANA SPS11. Please update after you have upgraded to HANA SPS11.

Comment: Frank, I have tried to find out the way to create Hana SPS 11 Instance. But didn't get success. Could you please help me how can i create Hana SPS 11 Instance. Any refereces if you have..???

Comment: A HANA SPS11 system can be installed like any other HANA system (hdbinst or hdbupd) - see [HANA Install Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Server_Installation_Guide_en.pdf). If you don't want to install on one of your servers you could also use a HANA ONE instance - see [HANA One on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B009KA3CRY)

Comment: Frank, Things are running properly on SPS 10. I just changed two properties in hanaes-site.xml. I just set master ip in spark.vora.hosts and spark.vora.zkurls instead of setting all the ip's. Thanks for the valuable support provided.